# Script php which dynamically create site map

Tags: php

I have a question. I have site. In one page I want put edit box with button. When user put any url to edit box and press button, site must return sitemap (like this site www.xml-sitemaps.com/). Is there a script php, which creates a sitemap based on any url? I mean create sitemap generator.
My example code:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form id="CreateSiteMap" method="post" action="ParseUrl.php">
     <p>Input url site:</p>
     <input type="text" size="40" name="URL">
     <input type="submit" value="Generate">
    </form>
    <?php
        function ParseURL($URL_SITE)
        {
            //Create tree of site
            return array("/Contacts.html", "/FAQ.html", "/Index.html");//For example
        }
      if( $_POST["URL"]  )
      {
         echo '<div id="Sitemap">';
         echo 'Sitemap '.$_POST["URL"]."<p>" ;
        foreach (ParseURL($_POST["URL"]) as $i => $value) {
             echo $_POST["URL"].$value."<br/>";
        }
         echo '</p></div>';
         exit();
      }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think will be easy to create a file sitemap.php and add all the urls on it.

```
return array(
"users" => "application/controllers/users",
"secure" => "application/controllers/secure",
"advert" => "application/controllers/advert",
"notfound" => "application/controllers/Notfound",
"controller" => "vendor/controller",
"bootstrap" => "vendor/bootstrap",
"autoload" => "vendor/autoload",
"methods" => "vendor/methods",
"database"=>"vendor/database",
"model" => "vendor/model"
);
```

ofcourse you will not put database

Comment: It's impossible. I need create sitemap of any url. which user put!

Comment: you can store the urls in the database, and display them when you want